# Замена for на lambda

Tags: java, lambda

Только начал изучать лямбды и пытаюсь разобраться, как их правильно использовать. Есть метод encode, в нём цикл for ( или весь метод) нужно переделать с использованием лямбд, но я абсолютно не понимаю, как это сделать( если это возможно). В других темах искал, но ничего подходящего не нашел, в основном через foreach.Буду рад помощи или хотя бы обьяснению, с чего начать, спасибо. (метод кодирует ввод пользователя с английского в шифр Цезаря, shift-  это сдвиг кодировки).

p.s. и еще вопрос - зачем эта лямбда вообще нужна? Насколько понял из ответа преподавателя на курсах - только для уменьшения количества кода, так ли это? И насколько часто их используют на практике?

```
class CaesarCodec implements Encoder, Decoder {
    private static final String ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ";
    private int shift;

    CaesarCodec(int shift) {

        this.shift = shift;
    }

    @Override
    public String encode(String input) {
        StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            ret.append(ALPHABET.charAt((ALPHABET.indexOf(input.charAt(i)) + shift) % ALPHABET.length()));
        }
        return ret.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ, что лямбда-выражения нужны не для уменьшения количества кода - это плохой ответ (это просто приятный бонус), потому как не вносит никакой ясности. К сожалению, в рамках форума невозможно объяснить функциональную парадигму программирования, но пример привести можно.

Лямбда-выражения нужны для передачи поведения. Разумеется, мы можем использовать анонимные классы, но это похоже на решение, пока не появляется вложенность. Функциональная парадигма предполагает возможность передачи функции в функцию. И такая вложенность может быть очень длинной. В этом случае вас вряд ли спасут анонимные классы (по крайней мере мне сложно представить это).

Но остановимся на передаче состояния...

Я переделал ваш пример с использованием лямбда-выражений. Не обращайте внимание на статику и т.д. Пример нужен только для того, чтобы продемонстрировать работу лямбд и передачу поведения с их помощью.

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String initialString = "dima";
        final Algorithms algorithm = Algorithms.CAESAR;

        System.out.println("Initial: " + initialString);
        System.out.println("Algorithm: " + algorithm);

        final String encode = Coder.getEncoder(algorithm).apply(initialString);
        System.out.println("Encoded: " + encode);

        final String decoded = Coder.getDecoder(algorithm).apply(encode);
        System.out.println("Decoded: " + decoded);

        if (!Objects.equals(initialString, decoded)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Initial and decoded strings mismatch");
        }
    }
}

public enum Algorithms {
    CAESAR, MORSE;    
}

import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;

public class Coder {

    private static final char[] ENGLISH = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
        'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x',
        'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0',
        ',', '.', '?'};

    private static final String[] MORSE = {".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..",
        ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".---.", "--.-", ".-.",
        "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", ".----",
        "..---", "...--", "....-", ".....", "-....", "--...", "---..", "----.", "-----",
        "--..--", ".-.-.-", "..--.."};

    private static final String ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    private static UnaryOperator <String> morseEncode = input -> {
        input = input.toLowerCase();
        char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
        String str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ENGLISH.length; j++) {
                if (ENGLISH[j] == chars[i]) str = str + MORSE[j] + " ";
            }
        }
        return str;
    };

    private static UnaryOperator<String> morseDecode = input -> {
        String[] letters = input.split(" ");
        String str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < MORSE.length; j++) {
                if (MORSE[j].equals(letters[i])) {
                    str = str + ENGLISH[j];
                }
            }
        }
        return str;
    };

    private static UnaryOperator<String> cesarEncode = input -> {
        int shiftKey = 3;
        input = input.toLowerCase();
        String cipherText = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            char replaceVal = input.charAt(i);
            int charPosition = ALPHABET.indexOf(replaceVal);
            if (charPosition != -1) {
                int keyVal = (shiftKey + charPosition) % 26;
                replaceVal = ALPHABET.charAt(keyVal);
            }
            cipherText += replaceVal;
        }
        return cipherText;
    };

    private static UnaryOperator<String> cesarDecode = input -> {
        int shiftKey = 3;
        input = input.toLowerCase();
        String plainText = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            char replaceVal = input.charAt(i);
            int charPosition = ALPHABET.indexOf(replaceVal);
            if (charPosition != -1) {
                int keyVal = (charPosition - shiftKey) % 26;
                if (keyVal < 0) keyVal = ALPHABET.length() + keyVal;
                replaceVal = ALPHABET.charAt(keyVal);
            }
            plainText += replaceVal;
        }
        return plainText;
    };

    public static UnaryOperator<String> getDecoder(Algorithms algorithms) {
        switch(algorithms){
            case CAESAR : return cesarDecode;
            case MORSE : return morseDecode;
            default: throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Algorithm " + algorithms + " not supported yet");
        }
    }

    public static UnaryOperator<String> getEncoder(Algorithms algorithms) {
        switch(algorithms){
            case CAESAR : return cesarEncode;
            case MORSE : return morseEncode;
            default: throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Algorithm " + algorithms + " not supported yet");
        }
    }
}
```

Итак, обратите внимание на методы `getDecoder` и `getEncoder` класса `Coder`. Они возвращают переменную типа функционального интерфейса `UnaryOperator` типизированную `String`. Типизирован он так потому, что наши декодеры и энкодеры всегда принимают `String` и возвращают `String`. `UnaryOperator`  являются частью Java и типизирован из коробки одним дженериком, который определяет одновременно и тип аргумента и тип возвращаемого значения. Для `UnaryOperator` они обязательно должны совпадать. Если возникает другая ситуация, то в Java  есть множество готовых функциональных интерфейсов (либо вы можете создать свой).

Выше в этом же классе объявлены 4 переменные типа указанного интерфейса. Ведь независимо от кодировки и операции (кодирования и декодирования) сигнатура методов одинакова. Рядом с этими 4 переменными описана лямбда - фактически она является методом , который выполняет кодировку либо декодирование по определенному алгоритму (и переопределяет единственный метод своего функционального интерфейса). Таким образом, в переменную типа интерфейса мы фактически затолкали метод (поведение)!!!

Теперь методы `getEncoder` или `getDecoder` вернут переменную типа `UnaryOperator` в класс `Main`. В классе `Main` у полученной переменой `UnaryOperator` мы вызываем метод `apply` (он так называется потому, что `UnaryOperator` мы достали из коробки и именно так называется единственный метод этого интерфейса). В аргументы метода мы передаем строку, которую нужно кодировать/декодировать и получаем результат кодирования/декодирования.

Что произошло? Фактически методы, которые были описаны в виде лямбд в классе `Coder` мы передали на исполнение и исполнили в классе `Main`! Это и есть передача поведения. Попробуйте проделать такой фокус без лямбд и увидите, насколько это непросто. А теперь представьте лямбды, которые принимают в аргументах лямбды и могут быть переданы в другие лямбды. Примерно так выглядит функциональное программирование)))

Удачи в изучении

Comment: Спасибо, вижу эта тема глубже, чем казалась =) Буду разбираться

Answer (score 1):

```
    StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
    input.chars().forEach(c -> 
        ret.append( ALPHABET.charAt(ALPHABET.indexOf((char)c) + shift) % ALPHABET.length() )
    );
    return ret.toString();
```

Comment: Благодарю, так уже понятнее